# Not able to display the json data in coming from service in the below form in angular mat-table

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have data coming from service in the below json array.

```
    "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "roneName": "1",
      "description": "Test1",
      "companyId": 101,
      "permissionList": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "permission 1",
          "description": "",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "permission 2",
          "description": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "permission 3",
          "description": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "permission 4",
          "description": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "roneName": "Test2",
      "description": "Test2",
      "companyId": 101,
      "permissionList": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "permission 1",
          "description": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Test 3",
      "description": "Test 3",
      "companyId": 101,
      "permissionList": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Test1",
          "description": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test 2",
          "description": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "test 3",
          "description": "test 3"
        }
      ] 
    }
]
```

i want to display data in the angular mat-table in below format

```
**Permission Name**  **roleName1**          **roleName2**         **roleName3**
permission 1           checkbox checked       checkbox checked      checkbox checked
permission 2           checkbox unchecked     checkbox checked      checkbox unchecked
permission 3           checkbox checked       checkbox unchecked    checkbox checked
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
StackOverflow supports pleanty of markdown options to format your question to increase its readability. Please check out the following page and try to reformat your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: hey sunil, seems there is problem in the json format. try fixing it. Try it out here https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator or https://jsoneditoronline.org/